# Clear all Smart Lock Password credentials from App

Tags: android, authentication, google-api, google-smartlockpasswords

I am implementing Google's Smart Lock for Passwords on Android service on an Android app and while the provided API gives you the ability to retrieve saved credentials, save new credentials, save multiple credentials and delete specific credentials, it effectively provides no way to CLEAR all the saved credentials for a particular app.  Not only is there no direct API to clear all the credentials, but there is no programmatic way to list all of the credentials in order to delete them one-by-one.

While the user can log directly in their google account in order to delete the saved passwords directly, this does not fit into any reasonable user interaction flow.  The only other idea I can think of is to prompt the user with the list of credentials, have the user 'choose' one at a time and then delete the chosen credential, which also seems like a very unwieldy and confusing flow for users to follow.

I have tried the 'obvious' solution of passing a null credential to the `.delete()` API or creating a credential with a null identifier.

Is there any known method of doing this that does not result in a really terrible UI experience of the user?

Comment: I am the product manager for Smart Lock at Google, can you provide more detail on the context in which a user would want to delete all credentials (aside for testing during development). In practice, we found most people only have one account for third party services, and since they have opted in to save the credential, it is rare they would like to delete it. Hence the flow is not optimized for mass deletion.

Comment: I will concede that this is for edge cases.  Testing google services integration is complicated enough without having to dig into my account settings to delete saved credentials. For our users, they (unfortunately) sometimes share devices and don't log out properly. We also have users that (believe it or not) sign up with an incorrectly spelled username and then make a second account but will never use the first. Edge cases are by definition unusual, but managing them is key to having a polished, user-friendly product. Having developer-friendly APIs is also important.  Thanks!

Comment: Fair points. An easy way to test deleting credentials is do so at passwords.google.com (requires re-entering account password) or navigate to the Smart Lock / Passwords section of Chrome settings (but takes a minute or two to sync). Also check out the API to auto-fill the user's name and email address to avoid typos and make signing up easier in the first place: https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/retrieve-hints ... and if user selects a credential is invalid, you can call delete it, and ensure credentials are valid before offering to save them.

Comment: (and keep in mind that users are prompted before saving credentials, even on a shared device, so hopefully it is less common that someone ends up in that scenario ... hope some of these things help!)

Answer (score 3):

There is no way via the API to delete all credentials programmatically, since this is not a typical user action (and it is a bit dangerous to delete all the user's data, would probably need a confirm UI or undo, etc.)

But as noted in the question comments, it could come up in testing, so easiest recommendation is to clear out all saved credentials at https://passwords.google.com or chrome://settings/passwords (but it takes a minute or two for the changes to sync to the device).

If you have more feedback on a user interaction that would require this functionality in the API, please leave a comment!